# Salesforce- retrieve Contact.opportunites

Tags: salesforce, master-detail

Here is snippet I am using in my anonymous window . Purpose is to retrieve Opportunities of a contact.  Even after adding opportunity contact role , contact.Opportunities.size is resulting in zero (last debug line). Am I missing something ? you may use the below code directly.

Update: able to get size now but same logic doesn't work for code coverage in test class . details listed below:

- Only 'if' part of controller is covered and 'else' part is never covered even though size of contact.opportunities is more than 0.

Controller method :

```
public PageReference sendingEmail() { 
//contact1 has query records
sizeVar = contact1.Opportunities.size();
if(contact1.npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c>0 ) {
if(sizeVar==0) {
    // if size is 0 then navigate to a particular vf page
    
PageReference pr =  Page.NoDonationOrNoEmail; 
pr.getParameters().put('id',(String)contact1.id);
pr.setRedirect(true);
return pr;
    }
 else 
{ //when contact.opportunities size is more than 0 then navigate to 
other vf page. 
PageReference pr1 =  Page.NoPrint; 
pr1.getParameters().put('id',(String)contact1.id);
pr1.setRedirect(true);
return pr1;
    }
     
  }  return null;
}
```

> > Test Class:

```
//creating account
Account a = new Account();
a.Name = 'Test Co.';
a.BillingStreet = '298 S. Ringo Street';
a.BillingCity = 'Little Rock';
insert a;

    
//Creating contact
    Contact contact1 = new Contact();
    contact1.FirstName = 'Paul';
    contact1.LastName  = 'Test';
    contact1.AccountId = a.id;
    contact1.npo02__OppAmountLastYear__c=100;
    insert contact1;
    //creating opportunity
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    o.RecordType = [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM RecordType 
    WHERE Name = 'Membership' LIMIT 1];
    o.Name = 'New Record';
    o.StageName = 'Posted';
    o.AccountId = contact1.AccountId;
    o.CloseDate = Date.today();
     o.Description = 'Test Record';
    insert o;
   
    //creating opportunity contact role
    OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
    ocr.ContactId = contact1.Id;
    ocr.OpportunityId = o.Id;
    ocr.IsPrimary = TRUE;
    ocr.Role = 'Decision Maker';
    insert ocr;
    System.debug('created opportunity contact role for primary');
    Update o;
    

    contact1 = [SELECT Id, Name,(SELECT id FROM opportunities) FROM 
    Contact WHERE Id=:contact1.Id];
    PageReference pr =  Page.NoPrint;
    pr.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(contact1.id));
    Test.setCurrentPage(pr);
    ApexPages.StandardController cont5 = new 
    ApexPages.StandardController(contact1);
    BulkEmailController  testAccPlan = new 
    BulkEmailController(cont5);
    testAccPlan.sendingEmail();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create and insert a record, you don't get formula fields nor you can navigate lookup. The same goes with child relationship.
You have to query the fields you need.
Change `Update contact1;` to `contact1 = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contact1.Id];` and the last debug line will print `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ruben. I am able to retrieve the size now. However , the same logic is not working in my test class. I am editing my original post to add test class details that has similar logic. Thanks again for your inputs.

Comment: Hi @srikkanth007, could you please add the code of the controller's constructor to your post?